# How to connect to mongodb as a docker image from another container app

Tags: mongodb, docker

Firstly I pulled mongoDb image

```
sudo docker pull mongo
```

and run docker mongodb container:

```
sudo docker run --name database -d -p 27017:27017 mongo --noauth --bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

I see that my docker container works:

```
300b779a63a9        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes
```

and now Im trying to connect to it with my docker app

```
sudo docker run -v ~/Desktop/Template/universal_skillskill -it --link 300b779a63a9:300b779a63a9 alexa
```

and... Im getting a message that the connection is refused :(

```
Uncaught exception: MongoError: failed to connect to server [0.0.0:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017]
MongoError: failed to connect to server [0.0.0:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017]
```

I checked and my app works with mongodb installed locally but it doesnt communicate with docker mongoDb container :( What am I doing wrong? Could somebody smart help me please :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to connect to `300b779a63a9:27017` as this is the linked name that you gave for the mongodb.

Comment: like this in my container webapp   mongoose.connect('mongodb://:300b779a63a9:27017');

Comment: mongo:27017 worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Adding to previous answers if you are starting your container with these additional parameter for authentication

```
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

then use `authSource=admin` parameter as well
only passing credentials wouldn't work.

`mongodb://<user>:<password>@<container_name>:27017/$<DB>?authSource=admin`

I faced this issue. thought, this might help someone.

Answer (score 5):

try to connect with the name of your container `database` and not with IP.

Answer (score -1):

You should use IP address of the container (`mongodb://<mongodb_container_ip>:27017/`).
You can check the hostname of the MongoDB container by running the following command:

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' m1
```

In this case, m1 is the name of the MongoDB container.

Source: ChatGPT

Comment: Using ChatGPT to post answers is forbidden. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned